# How do I Convert NaN to a 0?

Tags: javascript, forms, nan

When a value is not entered in one of my forms, it creates a later result of NaN in the javascript. I just want to declare anytime NaN would show that it would instead show 0. I thought that by simply adding

```
<script>

a = a || 0

</script>
```

to the beginning of my scripts that it would be fine.

Is there anyway to say that NaN will just always equal 0, no matter what the situation?

Comment: isNaN() exists so you don't have to convert it to 0.

Comment: @Jordan You missed the point of the question. The OP wants `NaN` to always equal 0.

Comment: Right.. Why? Just use isNaN().

Comment: @Jordan I suggest you re-read the question thoroughly.

Answer (score 8):

`NaN` is a global object that you **cannot** override.

Reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/NaN

One alternative is to use `isNaN` then

```
a = isNaN(a) ? 0 : a;
```

Comment: There, I've clarified that you simply cannot screw with `NaN`. Better?

Comment: I don't think you've missed the point. Their code example is clear what they are trying to do and you have a valid solution.

Comment: @AshBurlaczenko Terry's edited his answer. It was different 5 minutes ago. Hence why I've deleted that comment ;)

Comment: Right. My bad. I assumed the OP understands the nature of `NaN`. Should have clarified this from the beginning.